# Controlling notepad from c# code

Tags: c#, .net

I am sending Keystrokes like %FO,^V,%O to notepad from my c# code.
I have written code to handle both conditions like whether the notepad is active or not active. 
For active notepad i am just acquiring the handle of it and setting the foreground window to notepad.

The code is working for non active notepad but for the active part it runs some time or fails sometime i.e it is not consistent.

```
    Following is my code:




    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }


            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string keys = "";
                string path;

                int iHandle;

            iHandle = NativeWin32.FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad"); 
            //acquiring  handle of notepad(active) 

                if (iHandle!=0)
                {
                    NativeWin32.SetForegroundWindow(iHandle);
                }//checking whether notepad is active

                else
                {

                    Process.Start("notepad");
                }//launching notepad when not active

               path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
               System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetNam().CodeBase);
               //path of directory 
                 containing file to be
                 opened and the code

               Clipboard.Clear();
               Clipboard.SetText(path + "\\Hello.txt");

               keys = "%FO";
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(keys);

                keys = "^V";
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(keys);
                keys = "%O";

                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(keys);


                Application.Exit();
            }
    }
    }
```

Can somebody tell me why the program is inconsistently running when the notepad is active.

Comment: Ugh, this is the *wrong* way to do UI automation. As you've discovered already, it's extremely fragile. More importantly, it's not even clear what the point of this is. For something as simple as Notepad, it's *way* easier to just drop a multi-line `TextBox` control onto your form, which you can control however you wish...

Comment: "or fails sometimes" -- remarkably vague, please elaborate.

Comment: wait, hasn't the wheel already been invented? :) take a look at the `RichTextBox`. You don't need to do all this "sendkeys to notepad" business. just put a multiline textbox in your own app.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with (at least) two applications - it is your app and notepad.exe
Note that according to [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs, there are a lot of limitations when you can use it successfully, e.g. "An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user is working with another window. Instead, Windows flashes the taskbar button of the window to notify the user." More relevant info can be found here: [How can I set a foreground window if SetForegroundWindow and ShowWindowAsync doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741514/how-can-i-set-a-foreground-window-if-setforegroundwindow-and-showwindowasync-doe)

Also, it would be great to learn what you are trying to achieve. If you just want to automate UI, please use [Coded UI tests instead.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681.aspx). For just displaying text, host a text box.